# Using native messaging within Selenium ChromeDriver?

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, google-chrome-extension, selenium-chromedriver, chrome-native-messaging

I'm working on a chrome extension that uses native messaging. Native messaging works great on my personal copy of Chrome, but I get error messages from the extension when using it in selenium via ChromeDriver:

```
Error in event handler for runtime.onMessage: Error: Attempting to use a disconnected port object
```

I'm loading the extension via the following protractor config:

```
capabilities: {
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    'chromeOptions': {
        'args': [
            '--load-extension=./build/chrome'
        ]
    },
}
```

Does one have to do something special to enable native messaging in ChromeDriver? I've tried adding our native messaging manifest file(s) to the global locations for both Chrome and Chromium, but still no luck.

Comment: Does it have the same id? To ensure it, add a `"key"` in manifest.json

Comment: @wOxxOm yes, we already have a static key in the manifest.

Comment: @kjb did you find a solution in the end?

Comment: @georgexsh Unfortunately not. We just had to give up testing on Chrome. It appears ChromeDriver, at least last time we checked, simply doesn't support native messaging.

Comment: @georgexsh just verified native messaging does work with chrome driver using selenium. are you getting the same error msg as in the question?

Comment: @RiwazPoudyal yes it actually works, good news! I must do something wrong the other day.

Answer (score 1):

as of 2018.11, with Chrome 70 and chromedriver 2.43, native messaging works well.